# How do I add Custom Rest API Swagger as per Magento documentation? in Magento 2.3.4

Tags: custom, rest-api, magento2.3.4, swagger

Can anyone please suggest how to add custom Rest API to Swagger documentation in Magento 2.3.4?

Answer (score 0):

To see the full list of services you may want to generate a full permission token from the admin panel.

1. Log into admin panel Navigate to `Systems -> Integrations` (under Extensions section)
2. Click on the **"Add a new Integration"** Button
3. Fill in the required fields and move to the API tab on the left, for **"Resource Access"** Select **All**.
4. Hit **Save** and in the grid view and click on **Authorize** button.
5. Grab the Access Token generated (and save the rest of the info).
6. Navigate to `/swagger` and paste that access token to see the full list of REST services on your site.

Comment: Ubed thats right but suppose i have created one custom rest api and  i want to add it to swagger documentation how can i achieve that

Comment: Have you created a custom module and created a rest API?